# How to prevent auto-correction of the position of the ContextMenu?

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I set the position of the context menu manually:

```
ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
....
cm.Placement = PlacementMode.Absolute;
cm.HorizontalOffset = xpos;
cm.VerticalOffset = ypos;
cm.IsOpen = true;
```

But when the menu is too close to the edge of the screen, the position is automatically corrected.
How to prevent auto-correction?

Comment: Works for me without correcting the position, how are you getting your xpos & ypos?

Comment: In Absolute Screen Coordinates.

For Example ypos=500 and Screen size is 1024*768 - ypos is top position for menu.
And ypos=720 menu appeared significantly above this point

Comment: Ah I see, I'd misunderstood your initial problem.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, we can't change the auto correction behavior of popup (ContextMenu is also a popup ) when it encounters a screen edge. Look into "When the Popup Encounters the Edge of the Screen"  topic in the following link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613596(v=vs.110).aspx